# How to make a paper wallet

Tags: wallet

What is the canonical way to create a paper wallet for a substrate based tokens?

I could probably take a wallet app, create new account, backup the seed, note down receiving address, and remove wallet app.

Is that correct? Am I missing something? 12/24 words seed will work with all other wallet apps or only the one I used to generate it?
Are there any more canonical ways?

Before removing wallet app I could probably deposit some dots and stake them so cold wallet will not suffer inflation. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

For better security on paper wallets, I have been using [Parity's bananasplit](https://github.com/paritytech/banana_split) to store my pieces of paper.

As long as the target wallet supports sr25519, you will be fine in restoring. If in doubt, first test via throw-away mnemonics to see if your target wallets do do the correct thing.

For my cold wallet, I do have a proxy setup that at least allows me to perform staking operations, e.g. change nominations. (Stuff like transfer I don't allow via the proxy as setup). there is a slight cost in setting up the proxy initially, but well worth it.

Comment: Is there any manual describing that?